# tests with jest don't run after updating babel in react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

Had to update babel at some points in my project, react, typescript and next

but now the tests are not read

After settings, a error persisted and if removed babel config, error in github actions

My package

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.2",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.7.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.17.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-stage-3": "^7.8.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.15",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.47.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.3.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.14",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.3",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
}
```

My babel.config with settings for run project

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'next/babel',
    ['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' }],
    '@babel/preset-env',
    // '@babel/preset-stage-3',
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta',
    [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
      { loose: false },
    ],
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings',
    [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
      {
        absoluteRuntime: false,
        corejs: false,
        helpers: true,
        regenerator: true,
        version: '7.0.0-beta.0',
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

My jest.config

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/.next/',
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    '<rootDir>/coverage',
    '<rootDir>/dist',
  ],
  moduleDirectories: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules',
    '<rootDir>/src',
    '<rootDir>/pages',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@src/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '@pages/(.*)': '<rootDir>/pages/$1',
    '@styles/(.*)': '<rootDir>/styles/$1',
    '\\.(scss|sass|css)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/assetsTransformer.js',
    '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/assetsTransformer.js',
  },
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/features/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    'src/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    'src/services/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    'src/utils/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  ],
  testMatch: [
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/strip-indent/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
  ],
};
```

This is my error, a loop

[image]

I need to help, i dont know